# Order of Postback event handler and Validate method of all validator controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm learning asp.net page life cycle.
I find an article on MSDN 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx
It says that

> If the request is a postback, control event handlers are called. After that, the Validate method of all validator controls is called, which sets the IsValid property of individual validator controls and of the page.

And the picture in the article also says validate fires after event handling.
If this is true how can I get status of validator when I handling the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validators are validated before their server side event handlers are fired, you can rely on e.IsValid in them, this definitely works, many people use it all the time.

Comment: I haven't read it, perhpas you are misinterpreting it, but i know from experiance that the server side validation event handler fire after the validation has taken place.  They would would not be very useful if they fired before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain the picture is correct, as by the time you are in the click event of a button, the validators have fired.  You call `Page.IsValid` to check and see if any validators have failed.

I've never used it, but the Page class also contains a collection of validators (`Page.Validators`).  You might be able to use that to determine which specific validators are failing.

Answer (score 0):

Page_Load event fires before the Control's Server Event. You can validate  the Page with **Page.IsValid** in Page_Load event and leave the Page Cycle to handle the rest. This is commonly used in most of the projects.

Answer (score 0):

In further confirmation of Ben Robinson's answer, it looks like Microsoft updated the documentation after this question was asked.  The MSDN article clarifies:

> If the request is a postback, control event handlers are called. After
>   that, the Validate method of all validator controls is called, which
>   sets the IsValid property of individual validator controls and of the
>   page. **(There is an exception to this sequence: the handler for the
>   event that caused validation is called after validation.)**

This is the correct behavior.  You can test this with a simple page:

Markup:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" ValidationGroup="test" OnTextChanged="txtTest_TextChanged" />
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="cvTest" runat="server" ValidationGroup="test" ControlToValidate="txtTest" ValidateEmptyText="true" OnServerValidate="txtTest_Validate" />
    <asp:Button ID="btnTest" runat="server" Text="Test" ValidationGroup="test" OnClick="btnTest_Click" />
</form>
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void txtTest_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void txtTest_Validate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
}

protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Set breakpoints on all the events.  Run the app, change the text in the box, and click the button.  You should observe that TextChanged fires first, then Validate, then Click.